# release coco2dx application in vs2015 to win7 msvcr110.dll is missing dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, release, coco2d-x

for debug version, missing MSVCP140D.DLL

for relase verson, missing MSVCR110.DLL

could any body tell me how to release coco app in vs 2015?

I've set all build settings to MTd for debug, and MT for release, and use of MFC: use static MFC.

and tried c++ redistributable for vs 2015/2012/2010/2008, no any luck.

Answer (score 0):

> release coco2dx application in vs2015 to win7 msvcr110.dll is missing
>   dll  So if you have such a problem with this error you should remove it quickly and to do it properly you simply must install such tool like fix dll one for example from this url: http://fix4dll.com/msvcr100_dll

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem it is enough to [download msvcr110.dll](https://fixdll.net/msvcr110) , we sure that file is not corrupted. Sometimes this type of issue is arise because it's main reason is that file is crashed or damaged.After that you need to reboot the computer.